# IntelliJ 13 not prompting for module creation for new projects

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ 13 does not prompt for module creation for new projects over existing sources. All prior versions of IntelliJ used to do so and it was very convenient. Is there a setting that can restore this functionality with IntelliJ 13?

Edit : To clarify, my existing directory structure has a "main" and "test" directory that has source code for the main project and the associated source code. Prior to IntelliJ 13, it would scan the root directory for sources and prompt for creation of a "main" module and a "test" module. This does not happen anymore. Intellij simply created one module at the top level directory.

Comment: File->New Module->Select Java->And do further what type of modulen you want.

Comment: Jetbrains support helped resolve the issue. With IntelliJ 13, we need to use the "Import Project" option and point the the existing source directory for it to scan sources and detect existing modules.

Comment: Yes it detects from ${module}.iml file. So please include that as answer for this question how you resolved it. Thanks

Comment: You don't need an .iml project file. This works for freshly created projects as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jetbrains support helped resolve the issue. With IntelliJ 13, we need to use the "Import Project" option and point the the existing source directory for it to scan sources and detect existing modules.